# Insert and Update at same time

Tags: php, mysql

```
 $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO categories (cd_title , cd_link )
                       VALUES ('$docuTitle','$linkTitle')");
```

This works fine, but i want to update these values in another field in same table. Once these two are successful i need to pass return values.

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE into categories WHERE c_name = '$catID'");
```

**I know that i am not using mysql escape or PDO...**

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: So what you are trying to ask here?

Comment: What do you mean? The question is hard to decipher.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at [mysql-good-way-to-insert-a-row-if-not-found-or-update-it-if-it-is-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763577/mysql-good-way-to-insert-a-row-if-not-found-or-update-it-if-it-is-found) for a explanations and pointers to [replace into](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) syntax

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, the `UPDATE` syntax should be:

```
UPDATE categories SET column_name = 'data' WHERE c_name = `$catID`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`"UPDATE categories SET cd_title = '$docuTitle', cd_link = '$linkTitle' WHERE c_name = '$catID'"`

Also see [the MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html), and beware of SQL injection attacks (search this site for "SQL injection" for some hooks)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for `UPDATE` should be:

```
UPDATE categories SET <colname> = <value> WHERE c_name = '$catID'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first insert the row, then do the update (Although I'm not sure of your syntax above), both within a transaction.